# Php and ajax multiple dropdown menu onChange function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to choose province on the basis of state selected. This option is working fine, but when I add a new dropdown box for district that depends on the province option, and so on, all other option are not working and are displaying all values from the database not on the basis of the selected drop down menu ...[![enter image description here][1]][1]

include.php code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Mysql not connected');
    mysql_select_db('location',$con) or die('DataBase not connected');
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax1.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Address<br/></h1>
        <form>
        <select name="state" style="padding:10px;width:200px;font-size:20px;" onChange="display(this.value)">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Country --</option>
        <?php
            $query1="select * from tbl_state";
            $query1_result=mysql_query($query1)or mysql_error();
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query1_result))
            {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['state_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </select>

        <div id="show_city">
        <select name="city"  style="padding:10px;width:200px;font-size:20px; " onChange="display1(this.value)">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Province --</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <br>
        <div id1="show_Dist">
        <select name="dist"  style="padding:10px;width:200px;font-size:20px;">

        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Dist --</option>

        <?php
            $query="select * from tbl_dist";
            $query_result=mysql_query($query)or mysql_error();
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
            {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['Dist_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Dist_Name']; ?></option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </select>
        </div>

        <br>
        <div id1="show_Dist">
        <select name="dist"  style="padding:10px;width:200px;font-size:20px;">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Tehsil --</option>
        <br>
        <?php
            $query="select * from tbl_tehsil";
            $query_result=mysql_query($query)or mysql_error();
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
            {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['tehsil_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['tehsil_Name']; ?></option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </select>
        </div>

        <br>
        <div id1="show_UC">
        <select name="dist"  style="padding:10px;width:200px;font-size:20px;">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Union Concil--</option>
        <br>
        <?
            $query="select * from tbl_tehsil";
            $query_result=mysql_query($query)or mysql_error();
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
            {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['tehsil_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['tehsil_Name']; ?></option>
        <?php
        ?>
        </select>
        </div>

        <br>
        <div id1="show_Villages">
        <select name="dist"  style="padding:10px;width:200px;font-size:20px;">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Villages--</option>
        <br>
        <?php
            $query="select * from tbl_tehsil";
            $query_result=mysql_query($query)or mysql_error();
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
            {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['tehsil_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['tehsil_Name']; ?></option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </select>
        </div>

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

getcity code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Mysql not connected');
    mysql_select_db('location',$con) or die('DataBase not connected');

    $state_id=$_REQUEST['state_id'];

    $query="select * from tbl_city where state_id='$state_id'";

?>
<select name="city"  style="padding:10px;width:200px;font-size:20px;">
<option value="" selected="selected">-- Select city --</option>
<?php
    $query_result=mysql_query($query)or mysql_error();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
    {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['city_name']; ?></option>
<?php
    }
?>

</select>
```

getdist.php code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Mysql not connected');
    mysql_select_db('location',$con) or die('DataBase not connected');

    $city_id=$_REQUEST['city_id'];

    $query="select * from tbl_Dist where city_id='$city_id'";
    echo "Error";
?>
<select name="city"  style="padding:10px;width:200px;font-size:20px;">
<option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Dist --</option>
<?php
    $query_result=mysql_query($query)or mysql_error();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
    {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['Dist_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Dist_Name']; ?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

ajax file:

```
// JavaScript Document
var XMLHttpRequestObject=false;
function display(state_id)
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
    XMLHttpRequestObject=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
    XMLHttpRequestObject=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState==4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("show_city").innerHTML=XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
    }
    }
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET","getcity.php?state_id="+state_id,true);
    XMLHttpRequestObject.send();
}
```

ajax1 file:

```
var XMLHttpRequestObject=false;

function display1(dist_id)
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
    XMLHttpRequestObject=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
    XMLHttpRequestObject=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState==4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("show_Dist").innerHTML=XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;

    }
    }
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET","getdist.php?city_id="+city_id,true);
    XMLHttpRequestObject.send();

}
```

**How can I use the AJAX file properly?**

Comment: you _"want to chow provine"_ ? what do you mean?

Comment: your `getCity` ajax call is returning `select` elements and then you are placing that inside another `select`. I believe what you should do is build only the `options` then append those results to your `select`

Answer (score 0):

See I Can't go through all your codes. I'm having my code. Just go through it.
Try using this. Use little brain. And, you will not have any problem. 
~ @imDEnam

**View.php**

```
<select class='form-control City' name='StoreCity' required>
    <option value="">Select City</option>
    <?
    $QueryCity=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM AubreeCities");
    while($RowCt=mysql_fetch_array($QueryCity))
    {?>
    <option value="<?echo $RowCt['ACityNo'];?>"><?echo $RowCt['ACName'];?></option>
    <?}?>
</select>
<div class='Stores'>
   //Here, we will show all details which is coming from AjaxSelectStores.php Page..
</div>


**Ajax Call**
$('.City').change(function(){
    var CityNo= $('.City').val();
    $.ajax({url:"AjaxSelectStores.php?CityNo="+CityNo,cache:false,success:function(result){
        $('.Stores').html(result);
    }});
});
```

**AjaxSelectStores.php**

```
<?
include("open-db-connection.php");
extract($_GET);

$RecentMonth=date("F");
?>

<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-2'><label>Select Store</label></div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <select class='form-control' name='StoreNo'>
            <option value="">Select Store</option>
            <?
            $QueryStore=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM AubreeStores WHERE AStoreCity='$CityNo' ");
            while($RowS=mysql_fetch_array($QueryStore))
            {?>
            <option value="<?echo $RowS['AStoreNo'];?>"><?echo $RowS['AStoreName'];?></option>
            <?}?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```